# Why calling some functions of the Object class, on a primitive type instance, need boxing?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-internals

I have discovered that if i run following lines of code.

```
int i = 7;
i.GetHashCode(); //where GetHashCode() is the derived
                 //function from System.Object
```

No boxing is done, but if i call `i.GetType()` (another derived function from `System.Object`) in place of `GetHashCode()`, a boxing will be required to call `GetType()`, Why its not possible to call `GetType()` on primitive type instance directly, without boxing, while its possible to call `GetHashCode()` without boxing ?

Comment: I am surprised that `GetType` is called at all. Since C# is statically typed and a *value type variable* cannot hold anything but objects of the value type, the type is determinable at compile type (it’s `typeof(int)`). So why issue a runtime call?

Comment: That's right but the intention here is to clear that, why things are not working the way they should.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key here is that `GetType()` is not virtual and cannot be overridden. Since a struct is effectively `sealed`, methods cannot be overridden any *more* than the struct, so the runtime and compiler can treat struct methods **that have been overridden** as static calls.

If you write a struct (rare) you **should** override all the methods like `ToString()`, `Equals()`, `GetHashCode()` for exactly this reason. If you don't it must box. However, `GetType()` **cannot** be overridden, thus needs boxing.

This actually leads to some odd edge-cases with `Nullable<T>` and boxing, since an empty `Nullable<T>` boxes to `null`, so:

```
int i = obj.GetHashCode(); // fine
Type t = obj.GetType(); // boom
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is that GetHashCode is implemented on System.Int32 directly, you call System.Int32::GetHashCode().  No need to box if you call a known member function on a value type.

Comment: So the functions which are not implemented on System.Int32 directly, like those from System.ValueType or System.Object cannot be called directly?

Comment: That is what ildasm has shown me so far.... When you call the base class function (like System.Object::GetType() boxing is needed. If you call a function implemented on the value object then no boxing is nessecary...

Answer (score 1):

Seems very close to [How is ValueType.GetType() able to determine the type of the struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926352/how-is-valuetype-gettype-able-to-determine-the-type-of-the-struct)?

Also related is [GetType and TypeOf confusion](http://msmvps.com/blogs/joacim/archive/2009/08/31/gettype-and-typeof-confusion.aspx)