# Fastest way to find median in dynamically growing range

Tags: c++, performance, median

Can anyone suggest any methods or link to implementations of fast median finding for dynamic ranges in c++?  For example, suppose that for iterations in my program the range grows, and I want to find the median at each run.

```
Range
4
3,4
8,3,4
2,8,3,4
7,2,8,3,4
```

So the above code would ultimately produce 5 median values for each line.

Comment: Can you show your loop for producing the above so we can add to it?

Comment: Is linear time update cost for an insertion / deletion "fast"? Without keeping track of a sorted list this is the fastest possible solution I can come up with...

Comment: Perhaps manage a balanced tree of values, rebalancing as you insert values, and take the root node to get the median. I think insertion is O(log n) and lookup of the root node pointer is constant.

Comment: Potentially useful previous thread on finding kth smallest element in BST http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329171/find-kth-smallest-element-in-a-binary-search-tree-in-optimum-way/2329236#2329236

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can get without also keeping track of a sorted copy of your array is re-using the old median and updating this with a linear-time search of the next-biggest value. This might sound simple, however, there is a problem we have to solve.

Consider the following list (sorted for easier understanding, but you keep them in an arbitrary order):

```
    1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5
//           *
```

So here, the median is `3` (the middle element since the list is sorted). Now if you add a number which is greater than the median, this potentially "moves" the median to the right by one half index. I see two problems: How can we advance by one half index? (Per definition, the median is the mean value of the next two values.) And how do we know at which `3` the median was, when we only know the median was `3`?

This can be solved by storing not only the current median but also the *position* of the median within the numbers of same value, here it has an *"index offset"* of `1`, since it's the second `3`. Adding a number greater than or equal to `3` to the list changes the index offset to `1.5`. Adding a number less than 3 changes it to `0.5`.

When this number becomes less than zero, the median changes. It also have to change if it goes beyond the count of equal numbers (minus `1`), in this case `2`, meaning the new median is more than the last equal number. In both cases, you have to search for the next smaller / next greater number and update the median value. To always know what the upper limit for the index offset is (in this case `2`), you also have to keep track of the count of equal numbers.

This should give you a rough idea of how to implement median updating in linear time.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's your good right, but please comment why.

Comment: If you are OK with linear time, you might as well just keep the array sorted. Inserting a single value into a sorted array also takes linear time, and would be much simpler than the algorithm above. (But the downvote - if any - is not from me.)

Comment: @Igorostrovsky You're right. I was so fixed on finding a solution without sorting, so I didn't see that this is a bad idea. Inserting in a sorted array is possible in logarithmic time, by the way (binary search).

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't insert in logarithmic time because you need to shift all elements. The full answer IMHO should say two things: 1. if you need linear time, just do one insertion sort step on each new value. 2. if you need logarithmic time, you'll need a data structure such as red-black tree, AVL tree, skip list, etc (any one of those would do).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a min-max-median heap. Each time when the array is updated, you just need log(n) time to find the new median value. For a min-max-median heap, the root is the median value, the left tree is a min-max heap, while the right side is a max-min heap. Please refer the paper "Min-Max Heaps and Generailized Priority Queues" for the details.

Answer (score -1):

Fins some code below, I have reworked this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275115/add-a-median-method-to-a-list) to give your necessary output

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string range = "7,2,8,3,4";
        decimal median = FindMedian(range);
        MessageBox.Show(median.ToString());

    }

    public decimal FindMedian(string source)
    {
        // Create a copy of the input, and sort the copy

        int[] temp = source.Split(',').Select(m=> Convert.ToInt32(m)).ToArray();
        Array.Sort(temp);

        int count = temp.Length;
        if (count == 0) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty collection");
        }
        else if (count % 2 == 0) {
            // count is even, average two middle elements
            int a = temp[count / 2 - 1];
            int b = temp[count / 2];
            return (a + b) / 2m;
        }
        else {
            // count is odd, return the middle element
            return temp[count / 2];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like a hater is underway. My answer as well as the question got downvoted too, without leaving a comment.