# LinQ: C# sort an array while copying with some filters

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting, median

I have a case like, I have to fetch the non zero values of an array, sort them and find the median of values. I did as follows,

```
var array2 = (from t in array1 where t.array2 != 0 select t.array2).ToArray();
Array.Sort(array2);
var Median = array2.Length % 2 == 0 ? new List<double>() { ((array2[array2.Length / 2 - 1]) + (array2[array2.Length / 2])) / 2 } : new List<double>() { array2[array2.Length / 2] };
```

For now all going fine. But I am thinking of merging the first two lines in a single one like, copying the non zero values using orderby method. For this I have tried like,

```
var array2 = (from t in ipedsTableValue where t.array2 != 0 select t.array2).ToArray(t); // Not worked
```

Also suggest me if there are any super way to calculate median of an array in C# because that line is also looking so big and I am afraid that is not easily readable.

I have referred SO resource: [Add a Median Method to a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275115/add-a-median-method-to-a-list) Though it is working fine, I am thinking of some simple and efficient code with some less number of codes.
Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a Median Method to a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275115/add-a-median-method-to-a-list)

Comment: Modified your initial line, to suggest that you want to fetch non zero values in an array, sort them (which is required for a median) and calculate Median. It was misleading to suggest that you need to copy to another array, which caused the initial discrepancy in my first solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
var array2= (from t in array1 where t.array2!= 0 select t.array2).OrderBy(t => t).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's amazing. Thanks TomFarCry

Comment: Where's median calculation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq and a conditional operator.

```
var filterd = array1
    .Where(x => x.array2 != 0)
    .Select(x => x.array2)
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .ToArray();

var length = filterd.Length;

var median = length % 2 == 0
    ? (filterd[length / 2 - 1] + filterd[length / 2]) / 2.0
    : filterd[length / 2];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am getting error like, Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type I used.

Answer (score 1):

It should look something like that

```
var median = array2.Take((array2.Length%2 == 0) ? ((array2.Length/2) + 1) : ((array2.Length + 1)/2))
                    .Reverse()
                    .Take((array2.Length%2 == 0) ? 2 : 1)
                    .Sum(x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Array copy and ordering operation:

```
var filteredArray = array1.Where(x => x != 0.0).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Calculate Median

```
double midpoint = (filteredArray.Count() - 1) / 2.0;
double median = (filteredArray[(int)(midpoint)] + filteredArray[(int)(midpoint + 0.5)]) / 2.0;
```

Comment: I misunderstood your initial requirement as copying all the elements to another array except 0th element, I have now modified to remove  the 0.0 values and calculated median