# Calculating Median Absolute Deviation in C#

Tags: c#, math, statistics

I am required to perform a number of statistical calculations on a number set and one of the things I need to calculate is the Median Absolute Deviation. I was supplied with an ISO standard and all it tells me is

[image]

I have no idea what to do with that info as I do not have any statistical math training. As such, I can't translate the above into a C# function.

Comment: I should add that the otherwise useful Math.Net library does NOT include the MAD function.

Comment: whats med(x) ? median?

Comment: Math don't have this. You need to create your own method for this. You need to have a clear algo. From them then on its a downhill journey.

Comment: Could *med(x)* be the median of all x? (Ie. .50th percentile.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Median is a *middl*e element of the *sorted* array (or average of two middle items if the array has even items):

```
  double[] source = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

  Array.Sort(source);

  double med = source.Length % 2 == 0
    ? (source[source.Length / 2 - 1] + source[source.Length / 2]) / 2.0
    : source[source.Length / 2];

  double[] d = source
    .Select(x => Math.Abs(x - med))
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .ToArray();

  double MADe = 1.483 * (d.Length % 2 == 0
    ? (d[d.Length / 2 - 1] + d[d.Length / 2]) / 2.0
    : d[d.Length / 2]);
```

Comment: I am going to trust you because I like your beard. Thank you.

Comment: @Captain Kenpachi: instead of trusting, I'd rather run some tests ;)

Comment: Of course. I do have a set of results I can compare against.

Answer (score 0):

Make simple steps:
1. Find median `med` of  `x[]` array (you can just sort array and get middle value, but there are more effective methods)
2. Build array `d[]` of absolute differences with median
3. Find median of `d[]` array
4. Calc MADe

Answer (score 0):

How to program a function, which will calculate the median, you will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140719/calculate-median-in-c-sharp)

then your function can look like this

```
var arrOfValues = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

var di = new List<int>();  //List where all di will be stored
var median = calcMedian();  //See the link how to write it
foreach(var elem in arrOfValues)
{
   di.Add(Math.Abs(elem - median));
}
```