# How the get the mean, median and stdev from list

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get the mean, median and stdev result from the list of list.
Here is my initial code that needs to compute:

```
var myList = new List<List<double>>();

myList.Add(new List<double> { 1, 3, 6, 8});
myList.Add(new List<double> { 1, 2, 3, 4});
myList.Add(new List<double> { 1, 4, 8, 12});
```

And expected result is to get the mean, median, and stdev of first and last index only:

```
Mean:   1, 8
Median: 1, 8
Stdev:  0, 3.265986324
```

I tried to loop the list to get the average but not sure if this is the best way:

```
 foreach(var i in myList )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i[0].Average());
            }
```

Any suggestion/comments TIA

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I already stuck now. I can get the mean value using the .average function but I think the result is inconsistent sometimes it is correct and sometimes i'ts wrong

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a **string** `List`?

Comment: it's just a sample only. I put the variable as string coz this just came from the excel value

Comment: Can we assume each of the lists is in order (i.e. it will always be `{1,3,6,8}` not `{1,6,8,3}`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate median in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140719/calculate-median-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you started by showing how to calculate the `Average`. Note the use of `First` or `Last` to get the first / last entry from each of the sub-lists.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myList = new List<List<double>>();

            myList.Add(new List<double> { 1, 3, 6, 8 });
            myList.Add(new List<double> { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
            myList.Add(new List<double> { 1, 4, 8, 12 });

            var averageFirst= myList.Select(z => z.First()).Average();
            var averageLast = myList.Select(z => z.Last()).Average();

            Console.WriteLine(averageFirst);
            Console.WriteLine(averageLast);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! this one works on me but how about the median and stdev is there a function as well or do I need to write the formula manually?

Comment: Ok I got it now by just putting the number of index that I need. cool very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'll join forces with [@mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) (first and last)

Which is to say,

```
var listOfFirstValues = myList.Select(z => z.First()).ToList();
var listOfLastValues = myList.Select(z => z.Last()).ToList();
```

**Mean**

```
var mean = myList.Average();
```

**Median** The middle of a sorted list of numbers

```
public double Median(List<double> numbers)
{
   if (numbers.Count == 0)
      return 0;

   numbers = numbers.OrderBy(n=>n).ToList(); 

   var halfIndex = numbers.Count()/2; 

   if (numbers.Count() % 2 == 0)
     return (numbers[halfIndex] + numbers[halfIndex - 1]) / 2.0;

   return numbers[halfIndex];
}
```

**Standard Deviation** a quantity expressing by how much the members of a group differ from the mean value for the group

```
private double CalculateStdDev(List<double> values)
{  
   if (values.Count == 0)
      return 0;

   var avg = values.Average();  
   var sum = values.Sum(d => Math.Pow(d - avg, 2));   
   return Math.Sqrt(sum / (values.Count()-1));
}
```

<sub>***Note*** : Totally untested, and lacking any sanity checks</sub>

Comment: For the CalculateStdDev, you need to have `if (numbers.Count <= 1) return 0;`