# c# vtable is only part of the type objects method table

Tags: c#, object, types, static, vtable

I'm learning aspects of the clr in c# and read about this topic in "clr via c# 4th edition".

1. It is said that each instance of a type has a pointer to a [vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413483/virtual-method-tables), 
   but in the book they didn't differentiate between static, non-static and virtual methods.  According to it all methods are declared in the method table withing the type object. So I think that "vtable" name is misleading, and the virtual methods table is actually only a part of the normal method table in each type object. Is that true?
2. That would make sense because when calling a virtual method, the object is also referenced and then the clr checks the objects type and calls the method associated with the objects class. Or am I wrong?
3. Another question: static and non static methods are also in the method table.  My understanding is that they are only differentiated by a parameter.  Non-static methods are object related, so when calling those methods, a this-pointer is passed in to reveal the object that called it.  Static methods do not need this parameter. Am I right?

I know this is quite theoretically but I hope there are people who can help me!

Really nobody?

Comment: I can't provide a thoroughly accurate answer myself, but this MSDN Magazine article is very informative. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx   This might help you.

Comment: It is called the "method table" in the CLR.  And yes, it contains all methods, not just the virtual ones.  So v-table really isn't an appropriate term.  Primary reason is that the jitter needs it to know how to compile a call, also important for reflection.  Yes, static methods do not have the hidden *this* argument.