# Boxing, a thing of the past?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any point in doing this?

```
public static void Write<T>(T value)
{
    textWriter.Write(value.ToString());
}
```

...as supposed to this:

```
public static void Write(object value)
{
    textWriter.Write(value.ToString());
}
```

Setting aside the obvious null dereference possibility, If I where to write a lot of value types using this method wouldn't the former be much better because it will have it's own version of the write method to call, or is it just gonna bloat the binary in terms of a lot of additional code being generated?

The performance implication of such a thing might be negligible, but I'm curious, it's a lot more compact than providing an overload for each and every value type in the BCL, like most writers in the BCL already do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I understand, in both cases boxing occurs.

The latter is obvious as the value is already boxed.

The former is less obvious, but as a virtual method is called on a valuetype, it will need to be boxed to perform the `callvirt`.

**Edit:** I just checked the emitted IL, and there is no explicit boxing occuring in the generic case. Something rings a bell though.

**Edit 2:** I might have been confusing myself with the case using interfaces. There clearly boxing occurs.

**Edit 3:** Boxing does occur, if `ToString()` is not overriden in the value type.

I get this from ECMA-335 part 3 pg 25 (only noting the last case):

> If *thisType* is a value type and
>   *thisType* does not implement method
>   then *ptr* is dereferenced, boxed, and
>   passed as the ‘this’ pointer to the
>   callvirt of method
>
> This last case can only occur when
>   method was defined on `System.Object`,
>   `System.ValueType`, or `System.Enum` and
>   not overridden by *thisType*. In this
>   last case, the boxing causes a copy of
>   the original object to be made,
>   however since all methods on
>   `System.Object`, `System.ValueType`, and
>   `System.Enum` do not modify the state of
>   the object, this fact can not be
>   detected.

**Edit 4:** [Here is a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926352/how-is-valuetype-gettype-able-to-determine-the-type-of-the-struct).

Comment: Are all method calls really virtual? I suspected only the interface situtation to makes boxing necessary, @Edit 3 now that is somewhat surprising. I would think it to be the other way around, though with value types it's a bit different since you can not have inheritance, thus there really can't be virtual methods on value types and btw, this is a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

- virtual calls can require boxing (as leppie already said)
- the generic is more compact in source, but not in JIT'ed code

Considering performance:

- the generic reduces binary size somewhat. JIT time and code locality remain the same, since only required overloads are jitted anyway
- if the method is not a simplistic as in the example, the boxing solution will involve less JIT calls and decrease code size (thus improving locality as well). This is an accumulative effect  hard-to-measure except in extreme cases.

The gist is: there's no one perfect method for all circumstances.

Comment: Actually, I just discovered that boxing is not needed in all cases (eg where a virtual method is overriden in a valuetype)  :) See my modification.

Comment: ahh.. interesting. Added weasel words ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will avoid boxing in most cases. I wouldn't expect that to make any significant performance difference in most cases though. As you say yourself, it's likely to be negligible.

I'd argue that it *does* add a bit of a burden in terms of readability though. I suspect that most people have a bit more cognitive load when trying to understand a generic method than they do a simple method taking `object`. Who's going to be using this method, and are they sufficiently happy with generics that it won't bother them?