# Inspecting double.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, clr, double, tostring

As a follow up to a question I had about optimising the conversion of double to string for memory (see [c# double to character array or alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914105/c-sharp-double-to-character-array-or-alternative/10914673#10914673)) I wanted to see how double.ToString() is implemented under the hood in .NET. When I use ildasm or DotPeek i get as far as:

```
[SecurityCritical]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public static string FormatDouble(double value, string format, NumberFormatInfo info);
```

or

```
IL_0008:  call string System.Number::FormatDouble(float64,
                                                  string,
                                                  class System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)
```

And can't drill further. I think if my understanding is right it's because this is a call into the CLR. I wanted to know is there any easy way to find out what the implementation is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since .NET Core is open source now, answer to this question can be updated. [MethodImplOptions.InternalCall](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/mscorlib.md#calling-from-managed-to-native-code) indicates `FormatDouble` is a [FCall](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/mscorlib.md#calling-from-managed-to-native-code), which is a mechanism of communicating to native implementation. You can find the native implementation of `FormatDouble` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype/number.cpp#L2085).

Answer (score 3):

What about looking at mono source code? Mono simply use IL to do the whole thing without any C code.

```
mcs/class/corlib/System/Double.cs
mcs/class/corlib/System/NumberFormatter.cs
```

Answer (score 1):

I think WinDbg would be helpful - and did you checkout the implementation in mono?

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 5, `FormatDouble` is now implemented in C#, the source code is available in the [dotnet/runtime repository](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/066a24c7493cb894bff1e4532b770a9c1f9c3f56/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Number.Formatting.cs#L520).