# How to "customize" the Name of a type, like Nullable?

Tags: c#

How does the `Nullable` class do it?

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public T Bar { get; set; }
}

var n1 = new Nullable<int>(123).GetType().Name; // "Int32"
var n2 = new Foo<int>().GetType().Name; // "Foo`1"
```

Is it possible to make `Foo` have the same type name, i.e. "Int32"?

Comment: Note that `Nullable` gets some very special treatment by the runtime.  In particular, if a `Nullable` without a value is boxed, the boxed object is `null` -- in contrast to every other value type.  My suspicion is that this is similar special treatment.

Comment: See also [How is ValueType.GetType() able to determine the type of the struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/926352/1207195). Because `Nullable<T>` is a `ValueType` and value types are boxed then it's what you get (see also [Nullable.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/nullable.cs) source code)

Comment: The answer is a combination of my comment and @AdrianoRepetti's. I will draft an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: No, you can't change the name of `Foo`. What you're seeing with `Nullable` is a side-effect of how nullable values are boxed.

---

There are a few things at play causing the behavior you see regarding the `Nullable` type:

- Invoking `.GetType()` on a value type causes the value to be [boxed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13055/501250).
- `Nullable` gets special treatment by the runtime regarding boxing.  **A `Nullable` itself is never boxed**, instead:

  - If the `Nullable` contains a value, that value is boxed (the `int` value 123 in this case).
  - If the `Nullable` does not contain a value, the boxing operation evaluates as `null`.

The result is that, in your code, `Object.GetType()` is seeing a boxed `int` value when it executes, *not* a boxed `Nullable<int>` object (because, again, that's impossible).  This is why the name of a nullable is the same as the name of its content.  This is the simplest way to demonstrate what's happening:

```
new Nullable<int>(123).GetType() == typeof(int)
new Nullable<int>(123).GetType() != typeof(Nullable<int>)
```

As a side note, because a nullable without a value boxes as null, [it's an error](https://ideone.com/x7kw6D) to invoke `.GetType()` on a null nullable!  This simultaneously makes sense (it's null, right?) and doesn't make sense (it's a value type... it can't *really* be null!).  When a nullable has no value, you **can** invoke methods *implemented or overridden on `Nullable` itself* (because these calls do not require boxing), but you **cannot** invoke methods *inherited from `Object` and not overridden*.

`Nullable` has a strange dual personality, and sometimes it results in surprises like this.

Now that we know what's going on with the `Nullable` case, we can see that `Nullable` doesn't actually rename itself -- the name of the type that you see is the result of nullable boxing behavior.